# Magnetic field around a current carrying wire with changing magnitude of current

Tags: magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

The magnetic field around a long, straight current carrying wire is given by $B = \frac{\mu i}{2\pi r}$ which comes from Maxwell's fourth equation,assuming that there is no changing electric flux as the current is steady. My question is, if there is a long ,straight current carrying wire and the current is changing,then should it follow the above relation? As now there is a changing magnetic field and therefore an induced electric field, therefore there will also be a electric flux present (changing or unchanging). Doesn't that effect the magnetic field according to Maxwell's fourth equation?

Comment: Have you tried to rederive the result from Maxwell's equations for your case ?